# How to pass extras within Notification?

Tags: android

I have 2 activities in my app and I would like activity X to popup a notification - once its clicked activity Y will open and read params from the notification.

So I've written this:

```
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    CharSequence tickerText = NOTIFY_TICKER_NAME;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PopTask.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("task", "http://www.google.com");
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Problem is, when I try to read the extras - i get null.

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oshafran,

In order for `putExtra()` to work in this case you also have to use `setAction()`.  I'm not entirely sure why this is the case...seems to be some quirk.  The value passed in `setAction()` can be anything.

Try:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PopTask.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("task", "http://www.google.com");
notificationIntent.setAction("MyIntent");
```

Comment: Thx! That was my missing link to make them work! :-) voted up!

Answer (score 0):

Probably, a bit better solution is to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when you create your PendingIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(YOUR_EXTRA_KEY, "Your Extra");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```